# CodeIgniter URL formatting

Tags: php, codeigniter

At this moment, I am accessing my project pages like this and this formatting is working fine:

```
http://localhost/Seven/index.php/admin_login/login  (FOR LOGIN PAGE)

http://localhost/Seven/index.php/secure/admin_news  (FOR ADMIN NEWS SECTION)

config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Seven/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

At this moment, I'm not using any `.htaccess` file as I couldn't access contents of my [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

#### My question

1. How can I remove the "index.php" bit from my URLs, so that I could access my project pages like the following?

   ```
   http://localhost/Seven/admin_login/login  (FOR LOGIN PAGE)

   http://localhost/Seven/secure/admin_news  (FOR ADMIN NEWS SECTION)
   ```

   and all other pages ????
2. I have two user folders in my project root directory ("Seven") for images and CSS, that is, "images" and "css". I am using my CSS and images like this:

   ```
   http://localhost/Seven/images/test-logo.jpg
   ```

   AND

   ```
   ../Seven/css/default.css
   ```

When I try to get rid of absolute paths, I fail to access my images and CSS contents on my web pages. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `config/config.php`, line 31:

Change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then use this `.htaccess` (put it to the main root `/Seven`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Seven
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Seven/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a note to make your life easier: do not supply `base_url` in the configuration unless you really need it.

I've never supplied it in any of my projects which makes it less painfull when uploading to multiple places (CodeIgniter can figure it out).

Comment: i agree! but to be sure i always use **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** inside

Comment: @ahmad.what could be the alternate solution?sorry.I am a new bee and would appreciate if you could explain it further?Thanks.